# Using Cypress with `mock-sockets`

Tags: websocket, mocking, cypress

I am trying to use `mock-sockets` with Cypress, setting up the mock in the `onBeforeLoad` hook for `cy.visit()` in my `beforeEach` block. I can get one test to work but when the mock setup runs on the next `beforeEach` I get an error that `A mock server is already listening on this url`.

### code under test:

(called from my React app's `componentDidiMount`)

```js
  subscribeToSettings(url: string): W3CWebSocket {
    let settingsSubscription = new W3CWebSocket(url);
    settingsSubscription.onopen = () => console.log('WebSocket Client Connected (settings)');
    settingsSubscription.onclose = () => console.log('WebSocket Client Disconnected (settings)');
    settingsSubscription.onmessage = (message: MessageEvent) => this.handleSettingsMessage(message);
    return settingsSubscription;
  }

  /**
   * Handler for websocket settings messages, which updates the local settings values.
   * @param message the websocket message
   */
  handleSettingsMessage(message: MessageEvent) {
    const updatedValues = JSON.parse(message.data);
    console.log('A message was received on the settings channel.', updatedValues);
    this.props.updateSettingsFromBackend(updatedValues);
  }
```

### cypress tests

```js
import { Server } from 'mock-socket'
import { defaultSettingsState } from "../../src/reducers/settings.reducer";
import { _createSettingsApiPutPayload } from "../../src/actions/settings.actions";

describe('mock socket method 1', () => {
  let mockSocket;
  let mockServer;
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/', {
      onBeforeLoad(win: Window): void {
        // @ts-ignore
        cy.stub(win, 'WebSocket', url => {
          mockServer = new Server(url)
          mockServer.on('connection', socket => {
            console.log('mock socket connected');
            mockSocket = socket;
          });
          mockSocket = new WebSocket(url);
          return mockSocket
        });
      },
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockSocket.close()
    mockServer.stop()
  });

  it('gets a message', () => {
    cy.contains('SETTINGS').click()
    const object = _createSettingsApiPutPayload(defaultSettingsState)
    mockSocket.send(JSON.stringify(object));
    cy.contains('Motion threshold')
  });
  it('gets another message', () => {
    cy.contains('SETTINGS').click()
    const object = _createSettingsApiPutPayload(defaultSettingsState)
    mockSocket.send(JSON.stringify(object));
    cy.contains('Motion threshold')
  });
});
```

Here are the logs from my console:

```
WebSocket Client Connected (settings)
mock socket connected at url ws://localhost:8702/PM_Settings
A message was received on the settings channel. {…}
mock socket connected at url ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/949/mhuyekl3/websocket
The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
Uncaught Error: A mock server is already listening on this url
```

I wonder if it has to do with that second call which is for some mystery url.

(Note: calling `cy.contains('SETTINGS').click()` at the end of `beforeEach` somehow doesn't work, even in that first test. Even when I have my app set to start on the settings page (instead of having to click to it from inside the tests),  clicking on `SETTINGS` from `beforeEach` still doesn't work even though we're already there. So that's kind of weird)

These cypress logs may also be helpful:
[image]

Comment: hi, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It only worked for me, when I moved server stopping into `WebSocket` stub:

```js
cy.stub(window, 'WebSocket', url => {
  if (mockServer) {
    mockServer.stop();
  }
  mockServer = new Server(url);
  mockServer.on('connection', socket => {
    mockSocket = socket;
  });
  mockSocket = new WebSocket(url);
  return mockSocket;
});
```

Im probably wrong, but I guess `afterEach` or `mockServer.stop();` is async thats why mock server fails to stop before new init